# Initial power up requirement

Tags: power-supply, switches

I want my circuit to be fail-safe. The requirement is that a signal from the processor should be able cut the power supplied to the processor. But when the power is switched back on, it should be able to power up normally.

I've been thinking whether to use relays, but it doesn't make sense. I am stuck on the part where I have to switch the power back on.

Any ideas on how to implement this on a circuit?

Comment: You may want to consider cutting the power to the devices that the processor controls using a watchdog timer circuit where the processor would have to periodically pulse the circuit to keep it active. Consider if some condition causes the processor to hang or get stuck in a loop somewhere. It may be unable to shut itself off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the processor to switch things off and have them stay off until some further stimulus, the approach given by Mr. Lathrop is a good one.  In some other cases, however, what is required is to have a signal from the processor which can kill power to everything for some (typically short) period of time and have it automatically come back on.  That sort of thing should generally be handled by using some sort of sequencing logic which can operate independent of the CPU.  The device should have a few states:

- Power-drain: Assert reset, disconnect CPU power, and possibly dump current from the CPU power rails until CPU voltage is below 1V.  Then advance to Power-Up [ignore CPU "kill" signal]
- Power-up: Assert reset and connect CPU power until CPU voltage is valid and stable.  Then advance to "run" [ignore CPU "kill" signal]
- Run: Deassert reset, and remain in this mode until either the CPU voltage falls below the safe operating level, or CPU asserts a "kill" signal; then go to "pre-drain" in case of power failure; perhaps to immediately to "power-drain" in case of "kill" signal.
- Pre-drain: Assert reset, but keep CPU powered on for some fixed short period of time before progressing to "power-drain".

If your device uses things like flash memory chips, it may be desirable in case of power failure to let chips run off residual power for a little while after resetting the CPU.  This will help to ensure that if the CPU manages to start a flash write just before it is reset, the write will run to completion.

Note that it's important to ensure that the transitions between the indicated states happen cleanly, and that there's no realistic possibility that e.g. coming out of power-drain mode, the CPU voltage might sag to a threshold which causes the CPU power to turn on just enough to prevent it from sagging further and advancing fully to "power-up" state.  Using positive feedback on the threshold detectors will help assure this; adding a secondary oscillator which can "nudge" things slightly may help as well.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way to do this is to put a P-FET in series with the processor's power.  A high value resistor pulls the gate high, which keeps the FET off if nothing else happens.

A pushbutton shorts the gate to ground when pressed, which powers up the micro.  The micro then holds the gate low thru a transistor.  The micro should be able to power up and actively hold the gate low within a few ms or at least a few 10s of ms.  That is still a "short" time to press the button from the user's perspective.  A cap on the gate line can keep it low for a while after being shorted to ground.

When the processor wants to power itself down, it simply turns off the transistor that was holding the gate low.

The reason not to have the micro control the gate line directly is that when off, the protection diode in the micro will pull the gate line low.  By driving a transistor to keep the gate line low instead, you get around this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @ Olin Lathrop . but is there a solution which doesn't require a push button.
I am looking for a circuit which automatically takes care of itself.

Comment: @user: Takes care of iself how?  How is the circuit supposed to know when to turn back on?  If you want a micro to be able to start up again on its own, then put it to sleep instead of cutting its power completely.  Some micros have sleep currents below 1 uA, which is even good enough to not significantly drain a coin cell.